# Windows 7 Enterprise and Ultimate Editions: Unix Support

Tags: unix, windows-7

I've read that Windows 7 Enterprise and Ultimate
support the running of Unix commands. How does
the system cater towards this functionality?
Does it have a shell? What file formats does
it recognize? ELF, a.out, etc? Does it have
any Unix libraries installed? Any BSD (or GPL?) code?

Comment: The official one is - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interix

Answer (score 0):

Here it is: http://www.cygwin.com/

"Cygwin is a collection of tools which provide a Linux look and feel environment for Windows."
"It is a DLL (cygwin1.dll) which acts as a Linux API layer providing substantial Linux API functionality."

There are several tools already and you can try to compile what you need if it's missing.
Read FAQ: http://cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html#faq.what

Comment: I know about Cygwin, it's been around for a while now, and Aptana even comes with a plugin in which you can type in a cygwin window. But I am not talking about Windows 7 Home Basic, Home Premium, and Professional, where you can install cygwin on top. I'm talking about the Ultimate edition of Window 7. What advantages does its Unix compatibility layer have over Cygwin? Thanks, John Goche